# Java code to get data from process control block

Tags: java, operating-system, ps

i need to work with Process control block of each individual process. Is there any chance to get data from PCB using java code?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm going to go with "zero chance," saving some sort of OS specific binary linked to a Java program.

Comment: Using *pure* Java code: no.

Comment: What exactly is it that you need to do with PCB? Do you need to get access only to a "friendly" processes which agree to cooperate and link-in some your library?